# How to use spinner provided in Material design lite?

Tags: material-design-lite

I want spinner to appear when page loads and then slowly fades away after the page has loaded. How to implement this functionality using material design lite?

Comment: Can you share what you already tried and where you're stuck?

Comment: smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/  ..... I am using the method explained in this post. But they have used a gif file and all i'm trying is with a inbuilt class mdl-spinner provided in material-design-lite.

Answer (score 4):

The HTML for the spinner is this:

```
<div class="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-active"></div>
```

the material design lite CSS and javascript files will parse the document and upgrade that to a spinner on page load. If you want to add this to the page after page load, then you'll also need to call

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

in your javascript to get it to re-parse the page and upgrade the new spinner. You can find the documentation about the different kinds of spinners supported in material design lite [here](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#loading-section).

Answer (score 1):

## MDL spinner on page load solution

MDL just provides the **spinner** and it's up to the developer to integrate it into the page for what ever your need's may be. In this case you want to use it on page load.

### Placing the spinner

To create a loading spinner you first need to place a `<div class="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-active">` at the top of your document. I suggest right above the closing `</head>` tag.

### Centering the spinner.

To center the spinner you can do it with **flex box** like so.
Place the spinner inside a container above the closing `</head>`

#### HTML

```
<div class="spinner">
  <div class="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-active"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

Centering the spinner with flexbox. The `spinner` is set to `display:none` to hide it from view atm . Adding a class of `spinner-on` and giving it the `display` property of `flex` that we trigger on with jQuery when we want to show it.

```
$spinner-size:100px;
html, body, .spinner{
  height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mdl-spinner{
  height:$spinner-size;
  width:$spinner-size;
}

.spinner{
  position:relative;
  //top:100px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.spinner-on {
 display: flex;
}
```

#### Trigger with jQuery

With jQuery we trigger our `spinner-on` class which brings spinner into view. Then we use fading functions to fade in the spinner and fade it out after a set amount of time. Overflow is also set se we can now scroll the page.

```
$(function() {
    var overflow = $('body,html, .spinner');
    $(".spinner").addClass('spinner-on');
    $(".spinner").fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $("body").fadeIn(2000);
        overflow.css('overflow','visible');
    });
});
```

#### [DEMO](https://codepen.io/kapena/pen/rdWmMx)